# Pattern not matching *(%(*.%))

Tags: lua, lua-patterns

I'm trying to learn how patterns (implemented in `string.gmatch`, etc.) do work in Lua 5.3, from the [reference manual](https://lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#6.4.1).

(Thanks @greatwolf for correcting my interpretation about the pattern item using *.)

What I'm trying to do is to match `'(%(.*%))*'` (substrings enclosed by **(** and **)**; for example, `'(grouped (etc))'`), so that it logs

> (grouped (etc))
>   (etc)

or

> grouped (etc)
>   etc

But it does nothing  ([online compiler](https://www.lua.org/cgi-bin/demo)).

```
local test = '(grouped (etc))'

for sub in test:gmatch '(%(.*%))*' do
    print(sub)
end
```

Comment: Why do you write `*.` instead of `.*`?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff I've wanted to match everything that is between ( and ), and by the manual, this is a pattern item, where a character class must be following \* (in this "following" term I understood, "declared after \*"). I think `.\*` ends up using the next character class (in the question example, `%`, at `%))`, same as `.*%`, I guess.

Comment: You're mistaken here, all those repetition characters `*`, `-`, `+` etc. comes *after* the char class you want to match. For example to match letters use `%a*`, `.*` will greedy match any character. Your example just uses `*` kleene star but nothing precedes it so it's not well-formed.

Comment: @greatwolf Thanks for the correction, English isn't my primary language, so I may noy read it properly. Though Portuguese is similiar sometimes!

Comment: For your example, you could try `%a+%s(%(.-%))`, which means match 1 or more letters(case insensitive) followed by optional space followed by any characters in `(` `)`. On match capture the stuff in the parenthesis.

Comment: @greatwolf I wasn't caring too much about the containing characters as it's a test, but thanks for the idea. Your example printed `(etc)`, just missed `(grouped (etc))` at first. (I've tried grouping the entire character classes into the pattern item *, but it did then nothing :/.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possibility -- using recursion:

```
function show(s)
  for s in s:gmatch '%b()' do
    print(s)
    show(s:sub(2,-2))
  end
end

show '(grouped (etc))'
```

Comment: Super nice solution, I just don't understand this very well this sub.

Comment: `:sub(2,-2)` simply removes the outer parentheses before passing it to next call, or else recursion would never terminate.

Comment: I see, I've tested... very nice

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this with `gmatch` but using `%b()` along with the `while` loop may work:

```
local pos, _, sub = 0
while true do
  pos, _, sub  = ('(grouped (etc))'):find('(%b())', pos+1)
  if not sub then break end
  print(sub)
end
```

This prints your expected results for me.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I've also did something like this while manipulating a little thing. I'm kinda confused why it'd not work with * :/ in gmatch(), however

Answer (score 0):

```
local test = '(grouped (etc))'

print( test:match '.+%((.-)%)' )
```

Here:

. +%( catch the maximum number of characters until it %( ie until the last bracket including it, where %( just escapes the bracket.

(.-)%) will return your substring to the first escaped bracket %)

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't match `'grouped (etc)'` or `'(grouped (etc))'` :/, but thanks anyways (I've tried grouping it). Also, I've changed **.+** to **.\***.

Comment: why not, you need catch 'etc'?

Comment: I did want to match every group in the string (which would be a substring enclosed by **(** and **)**), even nested. My last try using your pattern along with `gmatch()` was `for sub in ('(grouped (etc))'):gmatch '.*%((.-)%)' do print(sub) end`, and when grouping the entire character classes into a pattern item **\*** it does nothing: `'(.*%((.-)%))*'`, and when just grouped without pattern items, it only prints exactly `'(grouped (etc)'`, but I don't care very much about the parenthesis as I'm learning (for keeping: `'(.*%((.*)%))'`).

Comment: show full example ( your text) please, then get a full answer

Comment: see [code online](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_lua_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQManFhY1c5dGlDRnc) ,  it that you need?

Comment: Near, but it's not inclusively printing `'grouped(etc1)'` (should print it because `'grouped(etc1)'` is enclosed by parenthesis).

Comment: may be all groups in [this example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_lua_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMSnNidmlsU2xSVlk) ?

Comment: Almost there, but it doesn't print >= 3rd inner-nested groups (i.e. `'(grouped(etc3(etc4))'`) (it doesn't print `'etc4'`). I'm having some troubles with different outputs, so I can't be exact... thus I'm trying to avoid **.+**. A group doesn't need to contain characters.

Comment: Thanks for the time anyways ! I think what I've wanted to do is not directly possible with only one pattern at `gmatch()` (but should be!), both of your answers were helpful

Comment: for etc4 and another recursive group [try this example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_lua_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMbUMyT05iWmkyQ3c) and with one gmatch I think it's impossible to do this ^-)